# MySQL query to join two table having different columns

Tags: mysql

**Consider the below table T1**

FLOOR...ANIMAL...COLOUR

1...Cat...Black

1...Dog...Black

1...Cat...White

2...Dog...White

2...Dog...Brown

3...Cow...Brown

3...Dog...White

3...Cat...Black

**Now, I with query: Select * from T1 where animal='cat'; got this Table T2**

Table T2

FLOOR...ANIMAL...COLOUR

1...Cat...Black

1...Cat...White

3...Cat...Black

**The result I want is: All the elements present in Table T2 and only(FLOOR,ANIMAL) of Table T1. Something like the below Table T3:**

Table T3

FLOOR...ANIMAL...COLOUR

1...Cat...Black

1...Cat...White

3...Cat...Black

1...Dog

2...Dog

2...Dog

3...Cow

3...Dog

**How this Table T3 can be acheived? Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Please show the _entire_ expected output and clearly explain the logic behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try taking the UNION of two TABLES wherein the second TABLE should have its third column as empty string:

select * from T1 where animal = 'cat'
UNION
select floor, animal, " " as color from T1 where animal <> 'cat';

Comment: Thanks a lot.It really helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `case`

like this :

```
case when ANIMAL = "cat" then COLOUR else '' end
```